# Roots of polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, finite-fields

Over a finite field, such as $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, the number of roots of a polynomial is no larger than the degree. I'm interested in how does this generalize to $\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$.

I'm sure that this has been looked at, but I haven't been able to locate any relevant literature. Thanks!

Comment: The polynomial $x^2$ has precisely $p$ roots when $k= 2$.  So any answer will involve $p$, not just the degree of the polynomial.  If the reduction of the polynomial is separable, then you can use Hensel's Lemma to find the number of roots.

Comment: Sure, that's a good point. But what I'm interested in is some theory, or at the very least a structural result, a theorem, you know, something beyond mere doodles :)

Comment: I suggest you pick up any book with the statement of Hensel's Lemma and read that statement.

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with that lemma. But I'm not sure it says all there is to say about roots of polynomials over Z/p^kZ.

Comment: There's a classical theorem of Nagell and Ore in this direction. For an improved modern version, see Corollary 2 of Stewart's paper "On the number of solutions of polynomial congruences and Thue equations":  https://uwaterloo.ca/pure-mathematics/sites/ca.pure-mathematics/files/uploads/files/j-ams-1991.pdf

Comment: Maybe you look for the Igusa zeta function?

Comment: I'm sure you're talking about Hensel's Lemma. From it we get that when p is odd we also have the same number of roots.

Comment: Say, the polynomial $p^{k-1}(x^p-x)$ of degree $p$ is identical zero. For $d<p$, the maximal number of roots is $d\cdot p^{k-1}$ by the same trick. This is possibly not what you really need.